# hat is the normal vector to the 2D-line $ \ mx+ny=l \ $?

Tags: geometry

The normal vector to the plane $ \ ax+by+cz=d \ $ is $ \ (a,b,c) \ $.

What is the normal vector to the 2D-line $ \ mx+ny=l \ $ ?

**Answer:**

The line is a 2-dimensional line.

I think the normal vector to the line is $ \ (m,n) \ $

**Am I right ?**

Comment: yes..............................

Comment: Note that $mx +ny=mx+ny+0 \times z=l$ that is this equation is in fact for a plane at (x, y) plane(or a plane with z=0). so you  are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Select $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $\ell =m x_0 + n y_0$. Then the equation of the line can be written equivalently as $m(x-x_0) + n(y-y_0)=0$, which makes it clear that $(m,n)$ is a normal vector to the line.

Alternatively, note that this line is a level curve for the function $f(x,y) = mx+ny$. The gradient $\nabla f(x,y) = (m,n)$ is normal to the level curve through the point $(x,y)$.

Comment: which vector ?  $ \ [m \ \ n ]^t \ $ or $ \ (m,n) \ $

Comment: @yourmath I'm not totally sure that I understand what you mean by "which vector", but by $(m,n)$ I mean the vector in $\mathbb R^2$ whose first component is $m$ and whose second component is $n$. Whether you think of $\mathbb R^2$ as consisting of ordered pairs or $2 \times 1$ column vectors is a separate issue. (Personally, I usually think of $\mathbb R^n$ as consisting of $n \times 1$ column vectors.)